# first element is coming selected by default in list box

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

i am creating windows application. I am binding listbox with database. It is loading and first item is coming as selected. But I don't want this. How can I deselect by-default  item on loading in listbox

```
ListBox1.DataSource = dt;
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "JobName";
ListBox1.ValueMember = "JobName";
```

how can i solve this problem

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting, WinForm ?

Comment: yes. i am using winform

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Or

```
ListBox1.ClearSelected();
```

See: [ListBox.ClearSelected Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.clearselected(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Calling this method is equivalent to setting the SelectedIndex
>   property to negative one (-1). You can use this method to quickly
>   **unselect all items** in the list.

Remember to call any of the above after assigning your `DataSource`

```
ListBox1.DataSource = dt;
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "JobName";
ListBox1.ValueMember = "JobName";
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: its raising the exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Bheeshamteche, how did you add the `ListBox` did you add it through designer or did you create it in the code, Are you sure that `ListBox1` has been created before execution of the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

this will works

Comment: this is not working. its raising the exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
listBox1.SelectedValue = null;
```

Hope it solves.